# s4s-elt-invalid-content: Element 'attributeGroup' is invalid

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, xsd-validation, xerces

I'm about to fork an existing XSD, however, before touching it, I'd like to have a working toolchain. Enter Eclipse.

The XSD in question are:
http://aixm.aero/schema/4.5/index.html

The schema "AIXM-Features.xsd" is schema valid according to [this online tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) as well as `xmllint`:

```
$ xmllint --schema XMLSchema.xsd AIXM-Features.xsd --noout
AIXM-Features.xsd validates
```

When I validate it with Eclipse, however, the following line errors on every of its 34 occurrences:

```
<xsd:attributeGroup ref="Changes"/>
```

Here's the first validation error:

```
Description Resource Path Location Type s4s-elt-invalid-content.1:
The content of 'AircraftClassType' is invalid.
> Element 'attributeGroup' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
AIXM-Features.xsd /afmx line 919 XML Schema Problem
```

Any idea what's going on here?

BTW: Eclipse uses a Xerces-based schema validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently AIXM-Features.xsd is not written to be used directly alone.  As you've seen, it references a `Changes` attribute group without defining it or including any definitions of it.

Note that AIXM-Snapshot.xsd defines it to have have no attributes,

```
<xsd:attributeGroup name="Changes"/>
```

and AIXM-Update.xsd defines it differently,

```
<xsd:attributeGroup name="Changes">
    <xsd:attribute name="chg" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional"/>
</xsd:attributeGroup>
```

If you were to add

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="AIXM-Update.xsd"/>
```

to AIXM-Features.xsd, the error would go away.  Alternatively, you could define a wrapper XSD that includes both AIXM-Features.xsd and AIXM-Update.xsd.

Final note: The error message that you cite is overly broad.  Yes, "invalid" arguably applies, but really a better diagnostic would specify that the referenced `Changes` could not be resolved to an attribute group.